# Using jq and map to convert JSON objects with nested objects to Name=Value format

Tags: json, nested, jq, key-value

Completely stuck with this one.

I've got JSON Like this:

```
{
  "create_option": "Restore",
  "disk_iops_read_write": 120,
  "disk_mbps_read_write": 25,
  "tags": {
    "Monitor": "No",
    "RSVaultBackup": "2dc504bd"
  }
}
```

and with the following jq

```
.|to_entries|map("nfs-0_\(.key)=\"\(.value)\"")|.[]
```

I've got to this

```
nfs-0_create_option="Restore"
nfs-0_disk_iops_read_write="120"
nfs-0_disk_mbps_read_write="25"
nfs-0_tags="{"Monitor":"No","RSVaultBackup":"2dc504bd"}"
```

but the nfs-0_tags line section also needs to be in name=value format. What I want to end up with is this

```
nfs-0_create_option="Restore"
nfs-0_disk_iops_read_write="120"
nfs-0_disk_mbps_read_write="25"
nfs-0_tags={Monitor="No", VaultBackup="2dc504bd"}
```

I feel I should be able to recursively apply the map but for the life of me I can't figure out how that might be achieved.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Okay I think I'm getting a bit closer now with this

```
.|.tags |= (to_entries | map("\(.key) = \(.value)"))|to_entries|map ("\(.key) = \(.value)")|.[]
```

I'm now getting

```
create_option = Restore
disk_iops_read_write = 120
disk_mbps_read_write = 25
tags = ["Monitor = No","RSVaultBackup = 2dc504bd"]
```

But I need the tags line in curly braces {} with the key unquoted and the value quoted. Like this

```
nfs-0_tags={Monitor="No", VaultBackup="2dc504bd"}
```

EDIT:

I still want the output to look like this

```
nfs-0_create_option="Restore"
nfs-0_disk_iops_read_write="120"
nfs-0_disk_mbps_read_write="25"
nfs-0_tags={Monitor="No", VaultBackup="2dc504bd"}
```

after the jq runs

Comment: Do you need to quote the value? In the first 3 lines of your expected output they're quoted while the last one is not.

Comment: @dibery yep - i've edited the post to reflect I still need the value to be quoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `act.jq`:

```
def f:
 if .value|type=="object" then
  "nfs-0_\(.key)={\([.value|to_entries|.[]|"\(.key)=\"\(.value)\""]|join(","))}"
 else
  "nfs-0_\(.key)=\"\(.value)\""
 end;

to_entries|.[]|f
```

Invocation:

```
jq -rf act.jq file.json
```

Use `type` to check if we should go down. If the type of `.value` is `object` then we split it again and then collect the result; otherwise we just interpolate it. You can also write `f` function inline (i.e., after `to_entries|.[]`).

Comment: That's awesome! - Thank you so much. I'm going to take some time to dissect that but right off the bat sticking it in jqplay it works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that allows arbitrarily deep nesting and illustrates the use of recursive inner functions:

```
def pairs:
  def q:
    if type == "string" then tojson
    elif type == "number" then "\"\(.)\""
    else . end;
  def ip:
    if type == "object"
    then "{" + (to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value|ip)") | join(",")) + "}"
    else q end;
  if type == "object"
  then to_entries[] | ("\(.key)=\(.value | ip)")
  else . end;

pairs
```

Comment: Thanks - another superb bit of information - I've learned so much from these two answers much more than wading through the docs and stumbling around with my own experiments - Great forum!!